# Android Studio Spinner (in Kotlin) doesn't respond to any clicks

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, spinner, android-databinding

I am trying to get a spinner working with Kotlin, I have spent hours on it but to no avail. Whatever I do, it doesn't respond to items being selected.

Let's start with the code:

This is my xml layout: (only the spinner)

```
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/unitySelectionSpinner"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    />
```

My Fragment:

```
    import android.app.Activity
    import android.content.Context
    import android.os.Bundle
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.AdapterView
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
    import android.widget.Spinner
    import android.widget.Toast
    import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
    import androidx.navigation.Navigation
    import com.epfl.esl.organizer.databinding.FragmentCreateStorageBinding
    import com.google.firebase.database.*
    import kotlin.collections.ArrayList
   
    class CreateStorageFragment : Fragment(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    
        private lateinit var binding: FragmentCreateStorageBinding
        private lateinit var unitID: String
        val database: FirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("myDatabase")
        val storageRef: DatabaseReference = database.getReference("Units")
        var list = ArrayList<String>()
    
        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "We got the Key:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            var a = 7 / 0
        }
    
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Nothing selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            var b = 7 / 0
    
        }
    
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_create_storage, container, false)
    
            // Get the list of names of units from firebase
            storageRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener{
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    // Fill an ArrayList with all the unit names
                    for(unit in snapshot.children) {
                        list.add(unit.child("unitName").value.toString())
                    }
                }
    
                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
            })
    
            binding.addObjectButton.setOnClickListener{view: View ->
   Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_createStorageFragment_to_createObjectFragment)
            }
    
            return binding.root
        }
    
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
            val spinner: Spinner = binding.unitySelectionSpinner
            val spinnerArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(activity as Context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list)
            spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            spinner.adapter = spinnerArrayAdapter
            spinner.onItemSelectedListener = this
        }
    }
```

I feel that I've tried everything imaginable, including:

-Creating an independent class with the spinner functions (onItemSelected, etc.)

-Put everything in onCreateView, put everything in onViewCreated

-Creating an instance of spinner with AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener inside onCreateView

Whatever I do the result is always the same: the spinner is populated (all the firebase data is written into it properly) but it doesn't respond when I click on an item in the app. None of the toasts (or the crash that should be caused by the division by zero) are triggered. It simply closes on selection as a normal spinner would do.

I am not sure what I am missing here. Any ideas?

Comment: Your code works fine for me with the Firebase and DataBinding stuff stripped out fyi

Comment: I really need to have Firebase and the databinding in my code for the purpose of the project I'm doing. If I had to guess I would say that the databinding might bee the issue because the firebase code is essentially the same as what I have seen in other codes. Any ideas how I could do the data binding in the fragment without screwing up the spinner? Thanks!

Comment: Oh I just meant that I tried it without those (obviously I don't have access to your Firebase stuff, and I haven't used data binding) and it worked fine - there's nothing obviously wrong with your code, so I wanted to try it. Honestly I don't see why there'd be an issue if the Spinner is showing the data - that means you're accessing the correct instance, and setting the listener and the adapter on the same thing. If one works, the other should! It should also crash immediately (``onItemSelected`` fires when the Spinner is first displayed with the current item)